# How to Use Firebase Cloud Function to Create Email Invitation and Send it Automatically if I don't Have Google Workspace?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I read on other Stackoverflow post that we can send email using Cloud Function on this [repository](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/Node-8/email-confirmation). The setup said that we must register and set the gmail.email and gmail.password Google Cloud environment variables to match the email and password of the Gmail account used to send emails (or the app password if your account has 2-step verification enabled). For this use:

```
firebase functions:config:set gmail.email="myusername@gmail.com" gmail.password="secretpassword"
```

Actually, I have email using a domain registered on GCP as admin-super@www.had-felix.com and I don't have any Google Workspace subscription, so I don't have any gmail at this moment. Is there a way I can send email without using Google Workspace subscription?

Comment: You may be interested by this article: https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-send-e-mails-using-firebase-extensions-a10d7cd685c2 from the [Firebase Tips & Tricks publication](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks) on Medium

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me out, @RenaudTarnec

Comment: Glad I could help you Wege. And a warm hello to my friend and fellow Firebase GDE @GastonSaillen who wrote this tutorial ;-)

Answer (score 0):

What I read from [tutorial](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-send-e-mails-using-firebase-extensions-a10d7cd685c2) sent by @RenaudTarnec, I figured out that we must create a SendGrid account from link Google Cloud Platform in this [link](https://console.cloud.google.com/launcher/details/sendgrid-app/sendgrid-email). We need to choose the Plan, and I chose Free one. Click it and SendGrid page will be displayed. Wait for message from SendGrid which says it is done. Return to SendGrid Email API and click on Manage Provider. We need to clean all of the cookies from sendgrid.com before clicking Manage Provider. Otherwise it would end up error if you tried to sign up before on the same browser.

After that, you need to authenticate your domain and make sure to check return-path. That's it.
Thank you for helping me out, @RenaudTarnec.